# Зачем нужен with при открытии файлов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файловый-ввод-вывод, менеджер-контекста

Обычно, когда мне нужно открыть файл и считать с него все строки, я пишу что-то вроде этого:

```
f = open('data.txt')
data = f.readlines()
```

Однако существует рекомендация, говорящая, что это лучше делать с помощью диспетчера контекста:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
```

Вопрос: чем отличаются эти два фрагмента? Чем второй лучше первого?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: это называется "менеджмент контекста".

Comment: @insolor, а почему вы удалили метку with? Чем она плоха?

Comment: @Глеб это метаметка, что само по себе плохо. См. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1160. Она сама по себе бессмысленна, и в разных языках может означать совершенно разные вещи.

Comment: @insolor, а если ее заменить на python-with? Тогда она не будет метаметкой?

Comment: Можно, но не понятно зачем отдельная метка для полутора вопросов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, нужно закрывать файл после завершения работы с ним:

```
f = open('data.txt')
data = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

При использовании `with open` закрытие файла произойдет автоматически при выходе из этого блока (в том числе и при выходе из-за исключения или просто выхода из функции через `return`).

Если использовать код с ручным открытием-закрытием, и вылетит исключение между этими командами, закрытие не произойдет:

```
f = open('data.txt')
raise SomeException()
data = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

А при использовании `with open` - закрытие произойдет в любом случае.

Подобное можно реализовать через try-finally:

```
f = open('data.txt')
try:
   data = f.readlines()
finally:
   f.close()
```

но через `with` получится гораздо компактнее.

Comment: А что может случиться, если файл не закроется?

Comment: Ну например у вас программа периодически открывает и дописывает что-то в файл. Или читает и проверяет содержимое. Если вы после первого открытия не закроете файл, второй раз вы уже его не откроете.

Comment: Так ведь если вылетит исключение, программа по любому или завершится аварийно (больше ничего открывать не придется), или его отловят через try (то же, что у вас в конце).

Comment: Если try-except будет где-то снаружи (в вызывающей функции), то он ничего не будет знать про то что файл нужно закрыть. Он может например залогировать ошибку или вывести сообщение пользователю, но файл так и останется висеть открытым. При повторной попытке открытия будет ошибка, пользователю возможно придется перезапускать программу. Вместо этого при вылете ошибки внутри блока with нужно ресурс освободить (закрыть файл), а ошибку уже пробросить дальше.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Теперь всегда буду открывать через with)

Answer (score 5):

Второй закрывает файл после выхода из `with`.

Полезная привычка к аккуратному управлению ресурсами. Если вы записываете в файл и не закрываете его вовремя, вы рискуете потерять данные. При чтении это не так важно.